# Resolving new instances with DryIoc when using Reuse.InWebRequest/Reuse.InThread

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, dryioc

I'm using DryIoc in a WebApi project. The default reuse is set to Reuse.InWebRequest. In some cases I need to resolve new instances during a request. When using Reuse.InCurrentScope I can resolve new instances like so:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo(IMyDependency dep, IContainer container){
        using (var scope = container.OpenScope()) {
            var newInstance = scope.Resolve<IMyDependency>();
            Assert.IsFalse(ReferenceEquals(dep, newInstance));
        }
    }
}
```

But when using Request.InWebRequest or Request.InThread (which are basically the same according to the documentation) no new instances are created, but already resolved instances are reused. I also tried to use `IContainer.CreateFacade()` but the result is the same.

I'm wondering if there is a way to force the creation of new instances (regardless of the specified reuse) without creating a new container from scratch.

### Update for clarification

I cannot use Reuse.Transient, because I need the same instance during the request 99% of the time. I need a new instance only when abusing the container as a service locator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may register service twice, one with scoped and another one with transient reuse. For the transient one specify a `serviceKey` when registering, and use it in service locator to identify the transient service.

Comment: I was considering this but didn't have time to test it.  Perhaps you could include this use case in your Reuse documentation?

Comment: Thanks, this works, at least to some extent. I wrote a little extension method that copies all registrations with a lifetime greater than transient and smaller than singleton but adds a service key. The only problem is, that resolving an `IEnumerabley<TDependency>` results duplicate instances, one for the default registration an one for the keyed one. Will see if I can work around it.

Comment: You can register a decorator for IEnumerable, to filter whatever services based on key: https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/Decorators#markdown-header-decorator-of-wrapper

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/ReuseAndScopes), `Reuse.Transient` should achieve what you are looking for.

```
container.Register<IFoo, Foo>(Reuse.Transient);
```

Comment: True, but that doesn't work for me here because I need the same instance 99% of the time. Clarified my question.

Comment: It looks like there may be a way to create your own Reuse implementation.
(see `IReuse`).  You could use that to pass in a flag to indicate you need a new instance.

Comment: In DryIoc v2.* you need to implement both IReuse, IReuseV3. IReuse is the obsolete one, so NotImplementedException will be fine. Here is the example of [custom reuse](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/src/f10182d271cfd9463c1599ea37e4c77ad685ae61/Net45/DryIoc.IssuesTests/Issue169_FalseAlarmCheckingScopeLifetimeConsistencyForFuncWrapper.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Issue169_FalseAlarmCheckingScopeLifetimeConsistencyForFuncWrapper.cs-42)